# Barcode Scanning Raspberry PI

Tags: pi-3, gpio, webcam

I want be able to scan barcodes using my raspberry pi 3, there are serveral barcode scanner/modules, but these are quite expensive. Would it be a option to use a webcam and use maybe a API which reads a picture for filtering a barcode ?

kind regards

Comment: What is your definition of expensive? A USB barcode scanner or even a wireless barcode scanner nowadays costs as low as US$25 online if you care to search online. Yes, you can use a webcam and there are library for creating your own barcode scanner, but a webcam without auto-focus will not very practical with quite frustrated and bad user experience, and it will not beat the price point and features (such as supports of multiple type of barcode formats) of commercial barcode scanner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One app I know that can read barcodes from a webcam stream is `zbarcam` which can be installed using `apt-get`.